# Import of commercial merchandise into the USA in a checked luggage

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I will be travelling from overseas and I want to bring a batch of cosmetics products into the US for resale. Estimated value of it is $2000. It will be packed in a regular checked luggage.

Will I face issues at PoE and how easy it will be to clear customs?
Am a US resident.

Comment: Do the cosmetics comply with applicable U.S. laws and regulations? http://www.fda.gov/cosmetics/cosmetics-international-activities/cosmetics-importers

Comment: In many countries you can only declare personal goods at customs at the airport, and any commercial imports need to be handled through other channels, as there's usually more paperwork involved. Don't know if that applies for the US. Also, what's your citizenship or residency status? If you're not a US citizen or PR, you may run afoul of legislation preventing you from working on a visitor visa.

Comment: @Traveller it looks like FDA regulations do not apply for soap. And that's what I want to bring.

Comment: @FallenBoeingRedemption According to https://cosmeticsinfo.org/products/soap FDA regulations typically apply, depending on the type of soap you want to import